# How can I make Alexa differentiate between "four" and "for"?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Let's say I have a skill that can be invoked like so:

```
Alexa, activate profile number 4 using pin 1 2 3 4.
```

4 and 1 2 3 4 are AMAZON.NUMBER and AMAZON.NUMBER_SEQUENCE slots. I figured the "number 4" would be enough context.

In debugging, it looks like Alexa reads this as:

```
Alexa, activate profile number for using pin one two three four.
```

Is there a way to make sure Alexa differentiates between that homophone?

Currently, the only solution I can think of is to not include that utterance and just go with:

```
Alexa, activate fourth profile ...
```

Answer (score 2):

That is common example Amazon employees use in every workshop to show how important to properly design voice interfaces. The context is matter. Because by saying "for miles" it can have a different meaning in the context. It could be:

- four miles
- for miles
- for isles
- four isles

Alexa cannot understand it without context. And you should create the context around your intents.

---

So, back to your problem.

If you want to capture numbers, you add [AMAZON.NUMBER](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#number) type to your slot. Using that Alexa will capture numbers from the user.

There is also an [AMAZON.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#four_digit_number) type you can find the use of.